# How to disable DPI scaling for certain built-in system applications?

Tags: windows-10, compatibility, high-dpi

On windows 10, most built-in programs work well with high DPI, but some  don't (the Hyper-V Manager for example).

For third party apps, I can change their compatibility settings.

How can I do this for a built-in app?

Answer (score 2):

Try the solution given in [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/blurry-text-and-icons-in-windows-10-dpi-scaling/90e23a2f-3be6-4fe3-aa04-be71c505bb15?page=2) :

> 1) Open Notepad and paste in the following lines:
>
> ```
> REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v DpiScalingVer /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00001018 /f
> REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Win8DpiScaling /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000001 /f
> REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v LogPixels /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000078 /f
> ```
>
> 2) Save the file as `DPI_FIX.cmd` someplace easy for you to find.
>
> 3) Open the Group Policy Editor (enter `gpedit.msc` from the search
>   bar).
>
> 4) In User Configuration, click on Windows Settings and then "Scripts 
>   (Logon / Logoff)".
>
> 5) Double-click "Logon" in the right pane.
>
> 6) In the Scripts tab, click Add, then Browse, then navigate to your
>   .cmd file, click Open, click OK, click Apply, click OK.
>
> 7) Sign-out or reboot.
>
> 8) Login to your account. It may not take effect the first time, and
>   if so sign out or reboot again. After that, it should work every time.

I suggest to first create a system restore point, just in case you need to undo this fix.

Another solution that is to be found on the Internet, is to use the program
[XPExplorer](http://windows10_dpi_blurry_fix.xpexplorer.com/), whose use is described in the article
[Fix Fuzzy Windows 10 Text on High Resolution Displays](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/fix-fuzzy-windows-10-fonts-high-resolution-displays/),
which does the above modifications on each login.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: this solution doesn't work for Windows 10, just 8.1. Marking as **community wiki** in case someone can tweak it for 10.*

Hyper-V Manager is just one of many snap-ins for the MMC (Microsoft Management Console) application.

The answer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/570785/) on ServerFault has a lot of registry changes that you can use to make MMC handle high-DPI mode better.